# Confused what I did wrong for $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + x^4} \, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, improper-integrals, algebras

I did $ x = u\sqrt{i}$

$$\sqrt{i}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 - u^4} \, du$$
$$\sqrt{i}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 - u^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + u^2} \, du$$
$ v = \tan^{-1}(u)$,$dv = \frac{1}{1 + u^2} du$

$$\sqrt{i}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1 - \tan^2(v)} dv$$
Using King's property, $\sqrt{i}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1 - \cot^2(v)} dv$.
If I is the integral, 2I =
$\sqrt{i}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1 - \tan^2(v)} dv$ + $\sqrt{i}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{\tan^2(v)}}
 dv$.
$$\sqrt{i}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1 - \tan^2(v)} dv + \sqrt{i}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{-\tan^2(v)}{1 - \tan^2(v)}
 dv$$
$\sqrt{i}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} 1 dv$ = $\sqrt{i} \cdot \pi/2$. By de Moivre's theorem $(\cos(\pi/2) + i\sin(\pi/2))^\frac{1}{2}$ = $\cos(\pi/4) + i\sin(\pi/4) $

so the answer would be $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}} + i\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$
But Desmos says it's real
What is wrong with the way I did it?
Thank you

Comment: You should not do $x = u * \sqrt{i}$. For solving it in a complex analysis way, maybe see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100339/integrate-int-0-infty-fracdxx22x122-using-residues

Comment: You can try to do $x = \frac{1}{t}$. It reduces to $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^2}{1+t^4} \text{d} x$, hence $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1+t^2}{1+t^4}dt$. Then do $t-\frac{1}{t}=u$.

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think of the first integral $$\sqrt{i}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 - u^4} \, du$$
as being an integral of a function defined on the complex plane, and the path of integration is along the half line $\{ \frac{u}{\sqrt i}  \text{ }| \text{ } u \ge 0
 \}.$