# Solving indefinite integrals using the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

While the Residue Theorem is used to easily solve integrals along improper bounds, I was wondering if it could be used to find indefinite integrals (antiderivatives) and when.

For example, on $\int\frac{1}{x^3+1}dx$ I was thinking to consider both $\int_{-\infty}^{n}\frac{1}{x^3+1}dx$ and $\int_{n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^3+1}dx$ to find the indefinite integral $F(n)$. If we were solving $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^3+1}dx$ we would create a closed contour including $-\infty$ to $\infty$ on the Real axis, so by a similar method we could 'split up' this single big closed contour into two (half as) big closed contours, one including $-\infty$ to $n$ and another including $n$ to $\infty$. One issue that I immediately run into is that there are singularities at $z=e^{i\pi/3}, e^{i\pi},e^{i5\pi/3}$ but each one would be at two different $z_0$ centers which depend on $n$ (and which integral it's within). I was thinking the contours could be centered at $z_0 = \lim_{R \to -\infty} \frac{R+n}{2}, \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{R+n}{2}$ respectively with radius $\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{R}{2}$ but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Variable of integration and limits of integration should not have the same symbol. Something like $\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{1}{x^3+1}dx$  is not meaningful.

Comment: @geetha290krm I've changed the point to n now, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrating $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^3}$ using residues.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565388/integrating-int-0-infty-fracdx1x3-using-residues)

Comment: @Sebastiano not at all, I just used that integral as an example but the main question is if it’s possible to solve indefinite integrals using the Residue theorem

Comment: @aj26 Ah now I have understood :-( sorry.